# MySQL error 10061

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm having a strange problem connecting via remote to MySQL. This is an internal LAN, so there should be no firewall issues. I've installed MySQL 5.0 and I've tried: `mySQL-front` and `DBTools-manager`. It's always error '10061', and yes, my 'mysql' database table permissions

I tried to restart the MySQL services, but it didn't work. I uninstalled it and removed the MySQL folder from `c:/Program Files` and installed mysql again but I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error `10061` is `Connection Refused`. This means that you are reaching the server, but the server says that it is not accepting connections on that port.

Here's some important information which may help you resolve the issue.

If you are using the loopback `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` on the client side, then you must be using the same on the server side. If the server is explicitly bound to a real IP address like 192.168.0.1, then it will not be listening on 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

You must explicitly bind to `127.0.0.1`, or you must bind to `all`.

So, if localhost or 127.0.0.1 isn't working on the client side, then try with the IP address.

Also, unless you have the ICMP service shut off, you will most likely succeed in pinging the loopback IP address, regardless of whether MySQL is running there. You're pinging your own machine.

Comment: This also solved my problem and saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

10061 is the following error.

> Connection refused. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is **inactive** on the foreign host.
See http://support.ipswitch.com/kb/WSK-19980709-EM01.htm for suggestions.

Comment: thanks for your reply but hostname resolution uses a local hosttable,and the port nuber is also correct even then same error.When itry to connect the following error come "Could not connect to specified instance Mysql error no. 2003 cant connect to mysql server on 'localhost'(10061). even when i ping its giving me reply.how to go about this error nuber 2003?

Comment: @pradnya, it's definitely **not** a MySQL issue, because if there is any connection to MySQL whatsoever you'll get a **different** error. Are you sure you are connecting to the correct port? `3306` by default, but perhaps you have it set to a non-standard number.

Comment: yes. Mysql is connected to port number 3306.I had tried to connect to port number 3307 but it gave the same error.